# How to check if a field value is a certain character length in a OLDEB sql select command?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I am reading from an access database using a C# OleDB connection. I don't want any results which are less than three characters in length.

My current code displays an "Invalid pattern string" error. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
string qry = "Select * from Table1 where ((CALLNO not like '') and " + 
             "((CALLNO like '%" + suggestedCallNo + "%') or ('" + suggestedCallNo + "' like '%' & CALLNO & '%')) and " +
             "((Len(CALLNO))>=3))";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(qry, myConnection);
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Without the `((Len(CALLNO))>=3)` this code works fine. Once I add the line however I get an *"Invalid pattern string"* exception once it goes to execute the reader.

A few things I tried:

Instead of `((Len(CALLNO))>=3)` use `(CALLNO not like '')`, this doesn't cause any error so I'm not missing brackets.

Trying to use single character wildcards like `'_'`, `'_ _'`, `'_ _ _'` so instead of `((Len(CALLNO))>=3)` I used `(CALLNO not like '_')`, this causes the same *"Invalid pattern string"* error. In fact the only things which I found not to throw an error are the empty string `''` and a full wildcard `'%'`.

I also ran the query from the query string directly in access and there I don't get any errors of any kind.

Thanks for any info,

LMB

Comment: What data source are you connecting to?

Comment: I'm connecting to an access database table:

    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\output.mdb")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `_`, you should use `?`:

> The patterns that you can choose from
>   are:
>
> - * allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)
> - ? allows you to match on a single character
> - # allows you to match on a single numeric digit

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

So you should be able to use `LIKE '???%'`

EDIT:
As David pointed out, it should be `'???*'` not `'???%'`.
However, the `LEN` function should work too, so there is some other problem, probably.

Comment: I tried using "(CALLNO like '???%'))"; which threw the same exception I also tried "(CALLNO like '?%'))"; and "(CALLNO like '___%'))"; all with the same effect, not working.

Comment: The wildcards in Jet/ACE's default ANSI 89 SQL mode are ? for a single character and * for multiple characters. You can't mix % in with that, unless you use the Access/Jet/ACE-specific ALIKE operator instead of LIKE.

Comment: I see from the tags that you're using OLEDB. In that case, the ANSI 92 wildcards are the ones you have to use, i.e., _ and %. ? and * will be treated literally in that case. I don't know what happens if you pass OLEDB a SQL statement using the ALIKE operator.